# What is the best type of paint for a basement floor?

Tags: basement, paint

I need to paint a basement floor that will see rugged use. What type of paint is appropriate for that? Or is maybe paint the wrong thing altogether and I should use a bake on plastic or something like that?

Before I paint, should I use a floor sander, like they use on wooden floors to smooth it out?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCC131UN43o.

Epoxy is my choice. Preparation is 90 % of the equation for success.

Research metallic epoxy for some incredible looks and spend some time watching how to videos that explain what makes a floor ready for this product.
[image]
[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCC131UN43o

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCC131UN43o

If your not looking for that fancy you can just use basic colors without metallic effect .

Comment: i was going to say epoxy but i didn't realize it could look so fancy; i'm used to the plain gray with confetti, like a car dealership....